# Getting error while running UI Tests in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-emulator, ui-testing

This is a simple UI test which I have created for a Xamarin.Forms application and I am getting this error while running tests.

Let me know how to solve this issue.

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: Looks like it couldn't uninstall the old apk from the emulator.

Comment: Are you hard-coding the package name in the UITest?

Comment: But i am getting same error in other emulators as well. Any work around for the same

Comment: @SushiHangover: Sorry i didnot understand. What do u mean by hardcoding package name ?